# REST Web Services - How to receive and parse form data from a webpage

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I have to research and give a presentation on receiving and parsing form data from a website but I'm unsure on how to parse the data and store it on a web server.  My professor described to me that I should focus more on the web server side of this.  I'm a little confused on whether I am supposed how (and what) it means to parse this info.

Am I supposed to grab the `$_POST['data']` in PHP and submit this to a web server?  There are no specifics on how to receive that data and parse it.

If someone could help me out with explaining to me how REST Web Services parse form data, I'd appreciate it.

The only hint my professor gave me was to search, "application form encoded".  I could not find an explanation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send data to your service by (jquery) AJAX, sending a json , jsonObject in this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        var jsonObject = {
            name: 'bobby',
            address: 'st. test'
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/myRestService.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            data: jsonObject
        });
    }
</script>
```

and further, in your service (myRestService.php) you receive json, and reply some response, in this example: true, and received name

```
<?php

//read received JSON (you can receive by $_POST if you want, just change this line)
        $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
//parse JSON to PHP object
        $data = json_decode($data);        

//return your service response
        $jsonResponse = "{ \"response\": true, \"text\": \"Hey, your name is: " .$data->name . "\"}";        
        echo $jsonResponse;
        exit;
}


?>
```

this is a very basic example how serivces works, and REST services are much more complex than your question, however this simple service example fit in your question because it's how REST services works as well.